# How can I debug React apps in WebStorm?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webstorm

I'm new to React and I need a way to debug my React applications in WebStorm.

I set breakpoints and the IDE stops at the breakpoint. But the application isn't executed completely and it stops at some point. Sometimes when I open Google Chrome Developer Tools, I see there is something happening line by line (probably debugging) in library files.

I tried blackboxing files in Google Chrome debugger and in my WebStorm I've checked the "do not step into library scripts" checkbox. I've also excluded some library files from debugging in WebStorm like "bootstrap" and "main.chunk.js". But still the debugger steps into these files.

How can I skip the library files and simply set a breakpoint in my application and debug only through my own files and components? Specially when the application is rendered a couple of times after changes in states, I need to have a good debugger and couldn't find any useful information unfortunately!

Comment: "do not step into library scripts" should normally help. Please make sure that exception breakpoints are not enabled in *Run > View Breakpoints*, *JavaScript exception Breakpoints*..

Comment: If this doesn't help and still both WebStorm and Dev tools debuggers hit breakpoints in library(?) files, it must the the issue with wrongs source maps or a bug in V8